# EclipseLink: ConnectionPools and native queries

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

We are using Spring (Eclipselink) on MariaDB. Our SQL via ORM result in a long lasting DB query. Therefore I need to refine it into a `nativequery` - which is no big deal by itself. Nevertheless the `Resultset` is limited by a `LIMIT` and I need a total counter for all found records. For querying the total counter I found for MariaSQL the following [solution.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

My question:

Is it save to query the two SQL command separately or should I send them once with a `UNION` combined?

The question arises due to the fact that between my query and the `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` the another query might interfere (with a request from the same Microservice) and dilute the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both queries are  done in the same transaction, the MVCC of INNODB should guarantee, that the results will not be influenced by other transactions.

see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-multi-versioning.html

Comment: But this means that I need to add `@Transactional` at the beginning of the method to  have transaction opened. Right?

Comment: That depends on the container you are using. Either there is a Transactionmanager running which handles the db-connections and the container recognizes the annotations or you define the transactions yourself inside your method using the EntityManager-object itself.

Comment: OK. I think I've got it. Thx for the hint.